# How to reconcile two collections

Tags: linq, t-sql, generics, collections, garbage-collection

I have 2 collections of the same type elements. Let's call those elements lettersOfAlphabet. Each letter has ID as int and Name as string.
So

```
ID   Letter
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
```

and so on.
First collection contains the alphabet, second contains selected letters.
In first step I create new selectedLettersCollection and this is easy. I simply add element from alphabet collection to selectedLettersColletion and immediately renove it from source collection (alphabet). So let's say I created collection of first 5 letters of the alphabet and saved it to SQL table. Now the alphabet collection starts at F and contains letters through Z, selectedlettersCollection contains letters A,B,C,D and E.

Now let's say I want to remove letter C form selectedLettersCollection and move it back to alphabet and get letter G from alphabet and move it to selectedLettersColletion.
What is the most efficient way to perform this opetation in LINQ, generic collections and/or T-SQL?

I would certainly create a new temporary collection of selected items and load selected elements into it. I would then perform my add remove operations. But so far the only thing that comes to my mind to reconcile those collections would be to iterate through selectedLettersColletion and new temporary collection and move elements accordingly but I was wondering if there is a method that would not require iteration akin TSQL's joins looking for NULLs.

Comment: wow...too many words, why just show your sql instead of words?

Comment: Why not just have a single collection with a boolean property selected?

Comment: @ Blam - ... because source collection is a reusable collection of (currently) 490 elements. Each of those elements could potentially be a member of infinite number of functional groups.

Comment: Then you need a question statement that better reflects what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use A and B for the table names. 
To move the row with Id = 1 from table A to table B use the following:

```
DELETE A 
OUTPUT deleted.Id, deleted.Letter INTO B
WHERE Id = 1;
```